# How to use Discovery XML in WOPI?

Tags: javascript, java, ms-wopi

As mentioned in this document http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html, I was wondering if there is a way to use the Action URL Dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "dynamically"?

When you load the [discovery file](https://onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery), you can dynamically build action URLs by replacing placeholders such as `<ui=UI_LLCC&>`.

Here's my [C# code](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/master/WopiHost.Url/WopiUrlBuilder.cs) which should be easily transformable to Java:

```csharp
    public async Task<string> GetFileUrlAsync(string extension, string wopiFileUrl, WopiActionEnum action, WopiUrlSettings urlSettings = null)
    {
        var combinedUrlSettings = new WopiUrlSettings(urlSettings.Merge(UrlSettings));
        var template = await WopiDiscoverer.GetUrlTemplateAsync(extension, action);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(template))
        {
            // Resolve optional parameters
            var url = Regex.Replace(template, @"<(?<name>\w*)=(?<value>\w*)&*>", m => ResolveOptionalParameter(m.Groups["name"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value, combinedUrlSettings));
            url = url.TrimEnd('&');

            // Append mandatory parameters
            url += "&WOPISrc=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(wopiFileUrl);

            return url;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note that the [WopiUrlBuilder](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/master/WopiHost.Url/WopiUrlBuilder.cs) uses [WopiDiscoverer](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/master/WopiHost.Discovery/WopiDiscoverer.cs) that facilitates low level operations upon the discovery file.